# hg nested repository settings

Tags: git, mercurial, subrepos, sparse-checkout

I have a third party nested git repo in my mercurial project and I want to share my local settings (sparse checkouts) for this repo with my team - is there any way to do this automatically?

/repo/nestedrepo/.git/info/sparse-checkout <- this is a local settings file, but I want everyone on the team to get it when they do a pull on the parent repo.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you really working with a *nested* repo, or a git subrepository?  Mercurial supports git repositories as tracked sub-repositories, which may help get you where you want to be.